# How do I make the mailto: subject and body tags change when I type in them in React

Tags: reactjs, scope, mailto

I am making a contact page for my portfolio and I wanted to add a small email form that just uses an anchor tag with a `mailto` inside of it to send an email. Inside the form you can add a title and a body and at the bottom there is an anchor tag with a `mailto` property that *should* change whenever I type something in the form.

[Image of the email form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CajKO.png)

When I hover over the anchor tag it previews the mailto, which in this case is correct because I haven't added any text myself.

[Image of link preview on the anchor tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwDWZ.png)

The issue I am running into is when I *do* add text, it still says the `mailto` is undefined.

[Image of the email form with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDbkJ.png)
[Image of the link preview still showing undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkcB8.png)

I tried using `sessionStorage` to update the text, but then the anchor tag only gets the correct data after I reload the page.

Is there any way for this to work so I can type some text in the form, and then click the 'Send' button and have it update the text without needing a refresh? I am getting stuck.

Below here is the code for the form, I use React and Tailwind.

```
      function contact() {
      return (
        let mailTitle;
        let mailBody;
        return (
            <SiteContainer>
                <>
                    <div className="md:col-span-2 row-span-3 bg-opacity-50 bg-white dark:bg-white/5 rounded-md p-4 border border-zinc-800/50">
                        <h1 className="font-bold text-sm dark:text-slate-500 mb-1">SUBJECT</h1>
                        <input
                            placeholder="How's it going?"
                            type="text"
                            onChange={() => {
                                mailTitle = event.target.value;
                            }}
                            className="w-full p-2 mb-4 rounded-md bg-slate-300/50 dark:bg-slate-200/5 text-sm placeholder:text-gray-600 dark:placeholder:text-slate-200/20"
                        />

                        <h1 className="font-bold text-sm dark:text-slate-500 mb-1">BODY</h1>
                        <textarea
                            onChange={() => {
                                mailBody = event.target.value;
                            }}
                            placeholder="Tell me about your day."
                            className="w-full p-2 h-36 mb-4 rounded-md bg-slate-300/50 dark:bg-slate-200/5 text-sm placeholder:text-gray-600 dark:placeholder:text-slate-200/20"
                        />

                        <div className="w-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center">
                            <p className="text-gray-900 dark:text-gray-300 text-sm"></p>

                            <a
                                target="_blank"
                                href={`mailto:westerdijk@pm.me?subject=${mailTitle}&body=${mailBody}`}
                                className="border border-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-200 dark:border-indigo-600/80 dark:bg-indigo-600/70 dark:hover:bg-indigo-500/70 flex flex-row items-center justify-center rounded-full px-5 py-2 text-sm font-medium transition-colors duration-75"
                            >
                                <span className="mt-[2px]">Send</span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            </SiteContainer>
          )}
```

I tried using `sessionStorage` to set the data in a handler and then get the data again in the anchor tag, this worked only half as I had to refresh the page for the anchor tag to fetch the actual correct data. If I didn't reload the page the anchor tag would only fetch undefined, or the text from the previous form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use react state (`useState` hook) for the local data in the component, in your case title and body.

use `useState` hook inside functional component, before `return`

```
function contact() {
 const [mailTitle, setmailTitle] = useState('');
 const [mailBody, setmailBody] = useState('');
 
 return(....)

}
```

set state on input `onChange`

```
// set title
onChange={() => setmailTitle(event.target.value)}

// set body
onChange={() => setmailBody(event.target.value)}
```

on `a` tag use like this:

```
href={`mailto:westerdijk@pm.me?subject=${mailTitle}&body=${mailBody}`}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I tried using `useState` before and I ended up with the issue that whenever I put it something in the form, the form would instantly reload.

Your answer doesn't have this issue and now it works as intended!
Maybe my bug was caused by me instantiating `useState` with `let` and not `const`. Regardless, thank you very much!

Comment: Setting the state in the `onChange` needs to be inside of an arrow function. Example: set title `onChange{setmailTitle(event.target.value}, this causes an infinite loop, unsure why. Exmple 2: set title with an arrow function `onChange(() => {setmailTitle(event.target.value)}}`, this works as intended, unsure why this works and the other way does not

Comment: updated the answer, you can read more about this issue [here](https://blog.devgenius.io/why-it-is-necessary-to-use-arrow-functions-with-react-event-handler-e0b278710310).